# Liferay 6.1 ga2 CE: Custom portlet deploy succeeds but does not appear in the portal

Tags: tomcat, deployment, liferay, portlet

I have searched for this problems few days now but can't seem to find the final solution.

The main problem is, that I deploy my portlet from the deploy folder of my tomcat directory, the .war file disappears and the portlet directory is created in the webapps folder. Now the tricky things start:

The log files of my tomcat shoot this lines:

```
[pool-2-thread-2][HotDeployEvent:109] Plugin MyFirstPortlet-portlet requires portal-compat-hook
[pool-2-thread-2][HotDeployImpl:233] Queueing MyFirstPortlet-portlet for deploy because it is missing portal-compat-hook
```

But the startup console for my liferay is telling me the deployment was successful. All the files are created in the right directory.

I already deleted the files in the temp- and work-folder of my tomcat, undeployed the portlet and even updated my liferay-sdk, nothing works though.

Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: You may want to check, if your sdk is the same version as the liferay portal. See: http://www.liferay.com/de/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/28958166

Comment: yes it is and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your plugin's `docroot/WEB-INF/liferay-plugin-package.properties` you'll find the entry

```
required-deployment-contexts=portal-compat-hook
```

This declares that your plugin requires the named plugin `portal-compat-hook`. Determine if you're really requiring this or delete it from that line, then redeploy.

As soon as you make the portal-compat-hook available to Liferay (or your appserver), it would actually deploy your plugin in Liferay and you can start using it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I downloaded the     portal-compat-hook now, but I don't know where to put it to make it available for my Liferay. Can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: as with all plugins, if you have an appserver that supports hot-deploy (e.g. tomcat, which you use), just put it in Liferay's deploy folder, e.g. `${liferay.home}/deploy`, through which you deployed your own plugin in the first place.